# Is the Google Cloud Vision DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION API configurable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, cloud-document-ai

I want to extract structured text from PDF contracts with the [Google Cloud Vision `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf).

Is the service configurable? For example, can I set the minimum vertical blank space the system uses to split paragraphs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION. For that level of customization, you can check out Google Cloud Platform's [Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/document-ai) product.

Comment: FYI, Document AI has an actively monitored tag [`[cloud-document-ai]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-document-ai)

---

I recommend referring to these videos/labs about Document AI

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/videos

And this page for more information about the data extracted from documents.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response